# How to change index.html reference using Grunt?

Tags: reference, gruntjs

When using grunt is it possible to alter the references within a html file.

I am altering the filename from `abc.html` to `abc.0bf5.html`

What I would like to do is within my index.html file alter the reference to the html template to use the latest html template.

Answer (score 0):

I see at least 2 ways of doing it:

- use `grunt-contrib-copy` to copy index.html to your build directory and set its `process` option: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy#process
- use [grunt-template](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/grunt-template) to generate your index.html